# Parameter error with Mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

When I run this Query I recieve

```
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /home/morgan58/public_html/wow/includes/index/index_admin.php on line 188
SELECT * FROM characters WHERE id=5
Warning: mysqli_free_result() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /home/morgan58/public_html/wow/includes/index/index_admin.php on line 194
```

The Query is running and it is strying to select the correct information, but for on the actual output it's giving me a fetch_array error; if anyone can see where the error lies it'd be much appreciated. Thank you.

```
<?php
  $adminid= $admin->get_id();
  $characterdb= 'characters';
$link = mysqli_connect("$server", "$user", "$pass", "$characterdb");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
$query = "SELECT * FROM characters WHERE id=$adminid";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
echo $query;
echo $row['name'];
}
mysqli_free_result($result);
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: [`mysqli_query`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) - Returns `FALSE` on failure.

Comment: Side-note, why don't you use [the object-oriented style](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php) to write? It is much clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an error in your query, so `mysqli_query()` is returning false. Check if it is valid before using it:

```
if ($result) {
    /// your code
}else {
    // your query failed
    die("Error: ".mysqli_error($link)); // will print your error
}
```

Comment: The original issue was found by adding the mysqli error and it was pretty simple, but hopefully someone can help with this. Now if I have `code` if($result){
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
echo '<br>'; echo $row['name'];
}
else
{
 die("Error: ".mysqli_error($link));
}`code` It doesn't display anything with the html echo in there; Any idea why by chance?

Comment: for testing, replace your echo with `var_dump($row)`, of it is not displaying anything, maybe you are getting 0 results

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM characters WHERE id=$adminid";
//further correction is single quote your variable in this case you are increase success run of your query
$query = "SELECT * FROM characters WHERE id='$adminid'";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

// its good you check before you leap
if($result){
    // your process
} else {
    echo "Unable to find given admin id";
}
```